# how to install precision trackpad drives in linux?

Tags: drivers, touchpad

how to install trackpad precision drivers on linux laptops?

i tried upgrading the drivers but it of really no use.
my trackpad doesnt have palm rejection too,but when i switch over to windows everything works fine especially the 3 finger gestures.
Please help me with this issue.
Thanks